# SQlLite Запрос,вычисляющий уникальные значения связанных столбцов

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть таблица с четырьмя значениями,это работник,проект и ID таска(задания) выполненного работником на проекте и часы,затраченные им на выполнение таска.
Нужно написать запрос,выводящий работника,проект и кол-во УНИКАЛЬНЫХ тасков выполненых работником на каждом проекте,а так же суммарное кол-во часов,затраченных им на выполнение тасков на каждом проекте.
Пробовал по-разному,но не могу понять саму концепцию как это сделать,так как знаю SQL только на уровне базы.Буду благодарен за помощь и,если можно,доходчивое объяснение,ну или просто решение,а там постараюсь разобраться.
Собственно,вот пример таблицы:

```
    CREATE TABLE EmployeeProgress
    ([EmployeeID] int, [ProjectID] int, [TaskID] int,  [Duration] int);
    
INSERT INTO EmployeeProgress
    ([EmployeeID], [ProjectID], [TaskID], [Duration])
VALUES
(1,1,1, 15),
(1,2,2, 34),
(1,3,5, 62),
(2,1,5, 23),
(3,2,6, 15),
(4,3,6, 18),
(4,3,7, 33),
```

Как просили в комментариях,вот так я сделал:

```
select  EmployeeID,ProjectID,TaskID,COUNT(DISTINCT TaskID)
from EmployeeProgress
where EmployeeID='4' and StageID='3'
```

Но проблема запроса в том,что он выводит только одно значение,даже если я уберу все условия WHERE,или оставлю тольок where EmployeeID = '4',оно всё равно выведет одно значение,первое попавшееся,в чём проблема - не пойму.

Comment: "Нужно написать запрос (`SELECT`), выводящий работника, проект и кол-во (`COUNT()`) УНИКАЛЬНЫХ (`DISTINCT`) тасков выполненых работником на каждом проекте (`GROUP BY`),а так же суммарное кол-во (`SUM()`) часов,затраченных им на выполнение тасков на каждом проекте." *Пробовал по-разному* Показывайте, Пусть и неправильные - но распишите свою логику, которую заложили в запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если правильно понял задачу, то вот так

```
select employeeid,projectid, COUNT(taskid), SUM(duration) from EmployeeProgress
GROUP By employeeid,projectid;
```

Comment: *если правильно понял задачу* Не совсем. "... кол-во УНИКАЛЬНЫХ тасков ..."

Comment: На самом деле,как я проверил,всё работает как надо,а по поводу уникальных тасков объясню:
Если,к примеру,работник сделал 4 задания,одно задание на первом проекте,одно задание на втором,ещё одно задание на втором,и одно задание на третьем.Для второго проекта будет две записи,то есть сколько тасков выполнено на этом проекте.Это и будет уникальным значением для заданий.Кажется,так себе объяснил,но лучше,наверное,не придумаю.

Comment: @ВладиславМоргунов Что за бред? это просто количество. Уникальные - это если работник в рамках одного проекта выполнил два таска номер 1 и два таска номер 2 (т.е. имеется четыре записи), то у него всего четыре таска, а уникальных только два.

Comment: @Akina Да,собственно это и подразумевалось,объяснять я не умею,к сожалению

Comment: про уникальность тасков не совсем понятно. Таски уникальны в разрезе проекта? 
Вот на основе данных в вопросе, напишите, какие данные на выходе Вы ожидаете